# dispatch action via props end up in maximum depth exceeded in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I'm trying to call my action via props in Next.js, but it keeps exceeding maximum depth and I couldn't understand why.

```js
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let rate_updated = [...this.props.previousArray];//copying store value to local variable
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.crypto_head_coins.length; i++) {
        //my code here
    }
    this.props.update_rate_array(rate_updated) // calling action to set array value in state
    this.setState({ rate_updated }); // setting array to state
}
```

this is how I'm mapping them

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    update_rate_array: Array => dispatch(update_rate_array(Array))
});
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   previousArray: state.crypto_head_update
});
```

Comment: Looks like `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` is called infinitely, because you dispatch an action which makes the component receive new props which dispatch an action and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `this.props` equals `nextProps` as follows and execute only when they are different.

```js
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if(this.props !== nextProps){
       let rate_updated = [...this.props.previousArray];//copying store value to local variable
       for (let i = 0; i < this.props.crypto_head_coins.length; i++) {
          //my code here
       }
       this.props.update_rate_array(rate_updated) // calling action to set array value in 
       state
       this.setState({ rate_updated }); // setting array to state
   }
}
```

Comment: it still exeeding stack limit

Comment: it works i had to check the this.props.crypto_head_coins !=== nextProps.crypto_head_coins and it works fine now thanks